# Why increasing decimal points not working for XY point features with sufficient precision length?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, editing, string

[image]

I am working with ArcMap 10.3.1 on a Lenovo ThinkPad (Windows 10). I want to display and copy x-y field values with more decimal positions (from 5 to 8; i.e. 34.3456 to 34.34561739), but after instructing and applying the numeric attribute changes under the field `Properties` there is no evident change in the table.

I am using a 'double' format.

Comment: Can you add screen shot of what you tried and what you have seen as described in your post.

Comment: Please also **edit the question** to specify the XYPrecision of the feature class. It seems likely that  precision of the coordinates is such that altering the column display units will only display additional zeros.

Comment: Hello, the coordinates are related to the location of rapid-transit station in Los Angeles. Here is a screen shot showing the X-coord and Y_coord fields and field editing windows:

Comment: How do I upload the screen shot to the text box?

Comment: Edit the question and there's a Image icon 6th from the left.

Comment: Tanks, just edited the question and posted the screen image

Comment: Try calculating the XY coordinates again with Calculate Geometry or AddXY.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, using the 'Calculate Geometry' command helped!